# Have Docker wait for Kafka to startup before running tests

Tags: jenkins, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    hostname: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka
    hostname: broker
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://broker:9092'
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  test:
    image: java:8
    volumes:
        - .:/src
        - ${GRADLE_USER_HOME}:/gradle_mount
    environment:
      - GRADLE_USER_HOME=/gradle_mount
      - SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP-SERVERS=broker:9092
    depends_on:
        - broker
        - zookeeper
    working_dir: /src
    privileged: true
    command:  "./gradlew --no-daemon clean test --info"
```

The tests pass locally but fail in Jenkins and I suspect it is because the tests are firing off before the Kafka service is running.

Is there any way to make the test container wait for the service on the Kafka container (broker) to start?

Comment: You could convert your command into a shell script and have it wait for kafka to be up before continuing. This shell script could be in a volume mount to keep things flexible

Comment: Do you know how to tell if Kafka is up via a script?

Comment: I've not used kafka but you could ping its port with `nc -vz localhost 9092` or   maybe something from here http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/1529kdm2h0/ping-kafka-server

Comment: The Confluent images contain a ready check already. You might want to double check your problem is that Kafka is not ready to serve.

Comment: That is likely the problem, is there a way to check if Kafka is ready to serve?